# Accessing environment variables from docker compose in Quasar app

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, environment-variables, quasar

I am wondering how should I serve and deploy Quasar app in docker on different environments. Env is injected to App during the build so if I use docker-compose on differents environment it will fail to change env inside app.

For now I found solution to create function to add my docker-compose env to my index.html  area and then parse it by another function to variables in program.

Is there more elegant way to do this? For example to create one env file with variables to all environment and in docker-compose just point which sets of variables should be used on that environment? (Ofc everything should work on docker-compose, I want to build only once and deploy to many environments).